# Error initializing complex filters. No such filter: '' in ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, terminal, ubuntu-22.04

I installed ffpmeg through terminal with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install -y mjpegtools`

I ran into an error after trying to run the following command:

`ffmpeg -y -i 1676476701.mp3  -filter_complex ";[0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,afade=t=out:st=63:d=5[afadedMusic];[segmentsAudio][afadedMusic]amix,asplit=2[mergedAudio][mpgAudio];, format=yuv420p,split=2[video][mpgVideo]" -map [video] -threads 16 -map "[mergedAudio]" -t 68 test.mp4 -map [mpgVideo] -threads 16 -map [mpgAudio] -target ntsc-dvd -aspect 16:9 -t 68 /home/artyst/projects/video-api/efs/assets/20230221212507_6353_6383_final_0_4X5fB1ejS2/deliverables/converted/video.mpg;`

I get an error as:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5620b8bf8680] No such filter: ''
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

My ffmpeg version is 4.4.2-0

I am a new beginner with ffpmeg and i only need it to have a project running for work. I am not able to figure out what filter is causing this.

Comment: [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Filtergraph-syntax-1): "A filterchain consists of a sequence of connected filters, each one connected to the previous one in the sequence. A filterchain is represented by a list of ","-separated filter descriptions. A filtergraph consists of a sequence of filterchains. A sequence of filterchains is represented by a list of ";"-separated filterchain descriptions." Your `filter_complex` stats with `;`, which probably means there is an empty filterchain in front of it. The same happens right before the `,` where you probably have an empty filter.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question; `ffmpeg` usage questions, according to the [tag], belong over at [su].